# trying to remove url parameter key with .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying for the past day to get the htaccess to drop the url parameter keys but not the values. Many forums and what every tuts I could find later, I have had very little success with it.

This is being done with wordpress and while I have the urls looking clean on the admin edit post, the url is not reflecting this.

So the url I have is:

> category/sub-category/?post=my-post

/sub-category is a working page by itself so htaccess needs to ignore the url until it has a ?post=my-post on the end.

Here is what I have so far. It has worked for others, but for me I am getting 404 errors

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# external redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^category/sub-category\?post=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^sub-category$ /sub-category/%1 [R=301,L] 

# internal rewrite back
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^sub-category/([^/]+)$ /sub-category?post=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Right now my current setup is also causing my /sub-category page (which does have content) to return a 404 error which is being caused by htaccess as it was working fine before I started to clean up the urls. So sub-category without ?post= appended needs to be ignored

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a doublon but i don't find the Question in question .. ^^

Try QSA flag

[See the appache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, while it didnt solve the problem the docs show it is flag I need to use.

Comment: yeah its a double, I have found two other threads on this particular subject, tried them both with variations of them as well, but no dice.